# How to get all valid fields for WIQL query using TFS API C#?

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, wiql

I found this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244668(v=vs.90).aspx

But I think that may be in regards to the database copy or something?

I just need to know if there is a way I can get a list of all the valid fields that can go into a SELECT clause in a WIQL like :

```
SELECT [System.Id],[System.WorkItemType] FROM WorkItem
```

I don't think WorkItemType is valid, when I tried outputting out it threw an exception:

```
Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", workItem.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Work Item Type: {0}", workItem.WorkItemType);
```

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: 2015 I believe, It's VSO, is it the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all fields defined for a team project collection using the **witadmin listfields** command:

```
witadmin listfields /collection:http://ｘｘｘｘ:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Check:　https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236909.aspx

Or you can install TFS Power Tool to check all fields in "Work Item Field Explorer".